# How can I update the Redux state with functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am developing a React web app and having hard times at it. I am trying to filter my posts with categories and on the server side it works well, however the problem is with redux.
This is my redux state =>
[image: categories]

There are category links in the sidebar and what I want is update the state after user selects one of the categories. So after changing `category` I will re-render the page that posts will come from updated category.

```
export const getPostsByCategory = (category) => (dispatch) => {

    const config = {
        withCredentials: true
    }

    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/?category=${category}`, config)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_POSTS,
                payload: res.data
            })
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

This is the sidebar component =>

```
export default function Sidebar() {

    const category = useSelector(state.category)

    onClick = () => {}

    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            <h3>CATEGORIES</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/fashion" className="link"><i className="icon1"><img src={icon1} alt="icon1"/></i>Fashion</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/house" className="link"><i className="icon2"><img src={icon2} alt="icon2"/></i>House</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/animals" className="link"><i className="icon3"><img src={icon3} alt="icon3"/></i>Animals</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/cars" onClick={onClick} value="cars" className="link"><i className="icon4"><img src={icon4} alt="icon4"/></i>Cars</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/sport" className="link"><i className="icon5"><img src={icon5} alt="icon5"/></i>Sport</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/books" className="link"><i className="icon6"><img src={icon6} alt="icon6"/></i>Books</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/movies" className="link"><i className="icon7"><img src={icon7} alt="icon7"/></i>Movies</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/games" className="link"><i className="icon8"><img src={icon8} alt="icon8"/></i>Games</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/landscape" className="link"><i className="icon9"><img src={icon9} alt="icon9"/></i>Landscape</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/shuffle" className="link"><i className="icon10"><img src={icon10} alt="icon10"/></i>Shuffle</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )

}
```

So how can I update `category` from this component? or can I?

EDIT: So I came up with a solution but it doesn't work either,

actions.js =>

```
export const changeCategory = category => {
    return {
        type:CHANGE_CATEGORY,
        category
    }
}
```

reducer.js =>

```
case CHANGE_CATEGORY:
        return {
            ...state,
            category: category
        }
```

sidebar.js =>

```
export function Sidebar(props) {

    const onClickHandler = (e) => {props.changeCategory(e.target.value)}
    

    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            <h3>CATEGORIES</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/fashion" onClick={onClickHandler} className="link"><i className="icon1"><img src={icon1} alt="icon1"/></i>Fashion</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/house" onClick={onClickHandler} className="link"><i className="icon2"><img src={icon2} alt="icon2"/></i>House</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/animals" onClick={onClickHandler} className="link"><i className="icon3"><img src={icon3} alt="icon3"/></i>Animals</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/cars" onClick={onClickHandler} value="cars" className="link"><i className="icon4"><img src={icon4} alt="icon4"/></i>Cars</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/sport" onClick={onClickHandler} className="link"><i className="icon5"><img src={icon5} alt="icon5"/></i>Sport</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/books" onClick={onClickHandler} className="link"><i className="icon6"><img src={icon6} alt="icon6"/></i>Books</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/movies" onClick={onClickHandler} className="link"><i className="icon7"><img src={icon7} alt="icon7"/></i>Movies</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/games" onClick={onClickHandler} className="link"><i className="icon8"><img src={icon8} alt="icon8"/></i>Games</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/landscape" onClick={onClickHandler} className="link"><i className="icon9"><img src={icon9} alt="icon9"/></i>Landscape</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/shuffle" onClick={onClickHandler} className="link"><i className="icon10"><img src={icon10} alt="icon10"/></i>Shuffle</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )

}

export default connect(null, { changeCategory })(Sidebar)
```

Comment: So I'm guessing your question is how to write the `onClick` handler to take a category and pass that on to `getPostsByCategory` action creator?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted to ask.